# What are the options for reusing the code in navbar on different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a problem with reusing one part of the code multiple times in navbar on different screen sizes.

I have tried to do ng-template and put it in different places to ng-container and control appearing with css on different screen sizes, but code in ng-template inside has components, that every time create a new instance.

```html
<nav class="main-menu">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="navbarRightTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{classes: 'middle-screen'}"></ng-container>
    <div class="main-menu-icon" (click)="toggleMenu()">
        <button mat-icon-button><i class="material-icons">menu</i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="main-menu-wrapper" [ngClass]="{'active': !isCollapsed}">
        <!--MAIN MENU CODE-->
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="navbarRightTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{classes: 'main-menu-right'}"></ng-container>
    </div>
</nav>
<ng-template #navbarRightTemplate let-classes="classes">
    <div [ngClass]="[classes]">
        <div class="nav-actions">
            <jhi-notification-bell></jhi-notification-bell>
            <!--SOME CODE-->
            <jhi-language-selection></jhi-language-selection>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I need only one instance of this reusable piece of code because jhi-notification-bell component has a connection to websoket or maybe, you know another way to decide this problem?

Comment: Is there any functionality change between screen sizes? Or just the styles?

If it's just the styles, why not just use media queries to style the nav differently based on the screen size?

Comment: Also, having multiple versions of this component doesn't necessarily have to mean that side-effects are duplicated (like websock connections, API requests, etc).

If there was mobile + web versions of this component, and the web component was destroyed when the mobile was created, both components can still share the same  connection after it's been initiated once.

Comment: There is the same functionality, changing only the place of appearing between screen sizes (>992, <992, <480). I handle it through media screens and different name of classes. Is there no way to use only one instance of a component in different places?